# How to get file name while monitoring a file with Apache's Tailer package?

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-io

I'm able to use org.apache.commons.io.input.Tailer package to tail multiple log files but unable to get their name. The available listener(TailerListenerAdapter) doesn't provide any methods to get the name of the file on which the event happens.

```
public class ApacheLogFileTailer {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String filelog1 = "C:\\Users\\eventfile1.log";
    String filelog2 = "C:\\Users\\eventfile2.log";

    ApacheLogFileTailerListener listener = new ApacheLogFileTailerListener();

    Tailer tailer1 = new Tailer(new File(filelog1), listener, 50);
    Thread tailerThread1 =new Thread(tailer1);
    tailerThread1.start();

    Tailer tailer2 = new Tailer(new File(filelog2), listener, 50);
    Thread tailerThread2 =new Thread(tailer2);
    tailerThread2.start();

    }
}

public class ApacheLogFileTailerListener extends TailerListenerAdapter {

@Override
public void handle(String line) {
    // How to get the name of the file changed ?? 
    System.out.println("Log file change "+line);
    super.handle(line);
   }

}
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way could be to set the thread name

```
    public class ApacheLogFileTailer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String filelog1 = "C:\\Users\\eventfile1.log";
    String filelog2 = "C:\\Users\\eventfile2.log";

    ApacheLogFileTailerListener listener = new ApacheLogFileTailerListener();

    Tailer tailer1 = new Tailer(new File(filelog1), listener, 50);
    Thread tailerThread1 =new Thread(tailer1);
    tailerThread1.setName("eventfile1.log");
    tailerThread1.start();

    Tailer tailer2 = new Tailer(new File(filelog2), listener, 50);
    Thread tailerThread2 =new Thread(tailer2);
    tailerThread1.setName("eventfile2.log");
    tailerThread2.start();

    }
    }

   public class ApacheLogFileTailerListener extends TailerListenerAdapter {

   @Override
   public void handle(String line) {
    // How to get the name of the file changed ?? 
    System.out.println("Log file change "+line);
    System.out.println("Log file change name "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
    super.handle(line);
   }

}
```